# How to store multiple values from SELECT in SQL Server? 

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Is there a way to store the results of a SELECT query in a stored proc using SQL Server?

In the example below I would like to store both "one", and "two" from the select query.

Example:

```
DECLARE @Values ???
SET @Values = (SELECT one, two FROM dummyTable)
```

Comment: You wish to grab multiple values from a single row or many rows?

Comment: Derived tables? http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/112098-1.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT @Value1 = One, @Value2 = two FROM dummyTable;
```

You don't have any arrays in SQL Server.

Comment: This is a very useful technique

Answer (score 5):

You can use a table variable for this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (one varchar(100), two varchar(100)

INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT one, two from dummytable
```

Like other variables, this won't be accessible from outside the scope of the proc.

It's also not good for large numbers of rows since the optimizer always assumes a single row for execution plans.

Answer (score 2):

If your query only returns a single row:

```
DECLARE @v1 int -- or whatever
DECLARE @v2 int
SELECT @v1 = one, @v2 = two
  FROM dummyTable
  WHERE id = 1
```

If your query returns multiple rows, you can use `SELECT INTO` to avoid having to declare a table variable:

```
SELECT one, two
  FROM dummyTable
  INTO #temp
SELECT * FROM #temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```